# In Rails 4 with devise gem, overriding after_sign_in_path_for is not effective

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In ApplicationController, according to devise docs, [How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in and sign out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out), the case switch when can not be reached, even in pry debugging console, it shows 'resource.class == User is true'.  I don't know what part of Rails processing I missed, any hint will be appreciated!

```
# ApplicationController.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
    binding.pry
    case resource.class
    when User
      puts "user redirect ==== "
      return session.delete(:return_to) || current_user_path
    else
      puts "super call ....."
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. Just need to get the resource class name using `resource.class.name` , so that you can compare it with a string such as `'User'` which is nothing but your class name.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
  binding.pry
  case resource.class.name   #=>this would return the class name i.e 'User'
  when 'User'
    puts "user redirect ==== "
    return session.delete(:return_to) || current_user_path
  else
    puts "super call ....."
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make workaround by creating `SessionsController` that inherits from `Devise::SessionsController`.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:session][:email])

    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to session.delete(:return_to) || '/authorized'
    else
      redirect_to '/sign_in'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out :user
    redirect_to '/signed_out'
  end
end
```

Point to it inside your `routes.rb` like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think your answer can be better if you can explain the thoughts behind customizing SessionController instead of overriding ApplicationController#after_sign_in_path_for .